# Is the total energy conserved in a moving reference frame?

Tags: classical-mechanics

I have a ball attached to a spring and the spring is attached to a wall. There is no gravity for simplicity. In the rest RF the oscillating ball energy is conserved: T + U = const. In a moving RF it is not conserved. I would like to see the shortest answer to the question "Why?".

|           <--  -->
|/\/\/\/\/\/\/**O**
|

=====>  $V_{RF}-->$

**Edit:** For those who has doubt - I choose the moving RF velocity equal to the maximum ball velocity, for example. Then the ball with its maximum velocity in the rest RF looks as still and does not have any potential energy in the moving RF (the maximum velocity is attained at the equilibrium position where no force acts). So T = 0 and U = 0.

At the farthest right position the ball looks as moving with $-V_{RF}$ and having a potential energy $kx^2/2$, both energy terms are positive ($v^2 > 0, x^2 > 0$). So now the total energy of the ball is positive and thus is not conserved. It oscillates from zero to some maximum value. Why?

Comment: Downvoters, give your short objections, please.

Comment: Minus one point for abusing the space that is reserved for questions for spreading primitive misconceptions about physics. Of course that energy is conserved in any - moving - reference frame. You may need to include the terms from the wall, too. But energy is conserved in any system with a time-translational invariance.

Comment: Thanks, Lubosh, you are so kind as usual. But I do not want to include the wall. I ask another question. So it is -1 to you.

Comment: Well, if you don't include the wall, the energy conservation law will fail by the oscillations of the kinetic energy of the wall. However, Noether's theorem still holds. If you derived the Noether energy properly, following her prescription, you would get the term from the wall even in the moving RF.

Comment: Lubosh, the wall does not oscillates. It is the ball that oscillates. Again, forget about the wall. Its mass is infinite and unknown. I did not take it into account in the rest RF, and I do not want to take it into account in the moving RF either.

Comment: In the normal frame, $H=kx^2/2+p^2/2m$ where $p=mv$. In a moving frame, one changes $x\to x+v_0 t$, so $L=m(\dot x+v_0)^2/2-k(x+v_0t)^2/2$. The canonical momentum for $x$ is $p=m(\dot x+v_0)$, and the energy will still have the same form as in the static RF and be conserved. To get a more usual form for the energy in the moving RF, you would normally subtract $p_{total}^2/2m$, but the momentum conservation is broken because the spatial translational invariance is broken, so the Galilean symmetry is broken as well and you can't switch to a moving RF in this way.

Comment: Surely the short answer to this question is just **yes**. Or do I misunderstand the question? I don't understand where the idea that it is not conserved has come from.

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea to rephrase the question and e.g. tag it as a [riddle]. Because it makes perfectly sense to consider such a RF and then address the apparent contradictions. One can learn a lot from studying such special situations.

Comment: I deleted the tail of the comment thread, since it was getting out of control. If there continue to be argumentative comments posted, I'll lock the question.

Comment: I think it's a good riddle to do with the idea of a constant potential function in one frame, becoming a time dependent one in a moving frame and so v + T is no longer constant. Of course, it depends on how you define your potential function.

Comment: This is not a terrible question--- it gets at the nontrivial mixing of momentum and energy conservation in a moving frame, and it deserves an answer. It's similar to the question "I am on a subway moving at 40mph, and I lean on a pole in the direction of motion. Why don't I get tired from all the work I'm suddenly doing?"

Comment: @david the question is closed, so why are you editing it?

Comment: @John: just trying to purge a tag from the system

Answer (score 3):

Energy is **not** a Lorentz scalar (or Galilean scalar). In different reference frames, the values of energies wil also be different, but this does not mean that there is no energy conservation. The energy is still conserved in **each** reference frame.

Comment: -1 for not answering my question. The energy is not only different but is not conserved.

Comment: @Vlad You're right that the answerer did not directly answer your question, but the name-calling is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

We must consider the kinetic energy of the wall to see energy conservation.  Taking the limit where the wall's mass goes to infinity does not alleviate this responsibility because although the wall's oscillations become infinitely small in that case, the oscillations in its energy do not.

To see this roughly, imagine that the wall is very massive and moving sinusoidally.  In the center of mass frame, the maximum speed of the wall is $s$.  Then the fluctuations in its kinetic energy are proportional to $M s^2$.  Thus, in the rest frame, we can make the wall's energy fluctuations arbitrarily small by increasing $M$, because $s^2$ will decrease more rapidly.

Now go into a moving frame where the average speed of the wall is $v$.  The fluctuations in its energy are now proportional to $M(v+s)^2 - Mv^2 \approx 2Mvs$ in the limit $v>>s$.  For fixed $v$, we can make $s$ smaller and smaller by increasing $M$, but as we do so the fluctuations in the energy of the wall don't change size because $s \propto 1/M$.'

Next note that the fluctuations in the energy of the ball in this frame are proportional to $mvs'$, with $s'$ the speed of the ball in this frame.  By conservation of momentum, $Ms = ms'$, so the fluctuations in energy of the ball and wall are about the same size in the moving reference frame.  Thus, we must account for both of them.

I'll give a fuller answer in one dimension for simplicity.  I'll first find the motion in the center of mass frame, then transform it and show that energy is conserved in the tranformed frame.

Let the ball have mass $m$ and the wall have mass $M$.  The spring constant is $k$.  Let the ball's position from equilibrium be $x$ and the wall's position be $X$.  The Lagrangian is

$$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\left(M\dot{X}^2 + m\dot{x}^2 - k(X-x)^2\right)$$

The equations of motion are

$$ -k(X-x) = M\ddot{X}$$

$$k(X-x) = m\ddot{x}$$

Adding these gives the conservation of momentum

$$\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}t}(M\dot{X} + m\dot{x}) = 0$$

In the center of mass frame this momentum is zero, so

$$\dot{x} = \frac{M\dot{X}}{m}$$

With the initial condition $x(0) = X(0) = 0$ we can integrate this to

$$X = -\frac{m}{M}x$$

The equation of motion for the small mass becomes

$$k(\frac{1}{M} + \frac{1}{m}) x = \ddot{x}$$

with the solution

$$x = A \sin(\omega t + \phi)$$
$$X = -\frac{m}{M}A\sin(\omega t + \phi)$$

with $\omega^2 = k(\frac{1}{M} + \frac{1}{m})$.

Now boost to a frame moving at speed $v$.

$$x = A \sin(\omega t + \phi) - vt$$
$$X = -\frac{m}{M}A\sin(\omega t + \phi) - vt$$

The potential energy is in the spring

$$U = \frac{1}{2}k(X-x)^2 = \frac{1}{2}k \left(A (1+\frac{m}{M})(\sin(\omega t + \phi) \right)^2$$

The kinetic energy is in the motion of the ball and wall

$$T = \frac{1}{2} \left(A \omega \cos(\omega t + \phi)\right)^2 \left(m + M(\frac{m}{M})^2\right)$$

Add these and applying the identity $\sin^2x+\cos^2x = 1$ gives

$$E = \frac{1}{2}k\left(A(1+\frac{m}{M})\right)^2$$

which is constant in time.

Comment: @Vlad did you down-vote?  The fact that it wasn't the language you wanted doesn't make it incorrect or deserve a down vote.

Comment: Yes, it was me. I said many times I do not want to consider the wall.

Comment: @Vlad It's there.  It's reasonable to consider it.  That was the point of my answer.  Your behavior is annoying.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.

Comment: The short answer I have been looking for from all of you is the following: "Because in a moving RF the ball potential energy depends explicitly on time." As you see, no wall mass is involved in it.

Comment: @Vlad That's just a general feature of mechanics.  It's completely unenlightening in this scenario and as vacuous as explaining why something is accelerating by saying "because there is a force on it".

Comment: You exaggerate, Mark. Everybody wanted to bring his wall into it but I asked to do without the wall mass.

Comment: Lubosh was really close to it: he wrote the potential energy with its explicit time-dependence. This should have been sufficient to give the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the wall has some large but finite mass. Then the actual motion of the system involves oscillations of the wall as well as oscillations of the mass. If you work out the total energy of the entire system, you'll find that it's conserved.

Comment: I know, Ted, I know. Where is your short answer to the post question?

Comment: If you're looking for an answer to the question "why is the energy of the ball not conserved?" then the answer is that there's no reason to expect the energy of just one part of a system to be conserved. Conservation of energy applies to the total energy.

Comment: And I apply it to the total energy E = T + U of the ball. In the rest RF it is conserved, in a moving RF it is not.

Comment: The simple problem here is in sharp contrast to the "big science" (at first sight) in Vladimirs pages. I recommend to have a visit there.

Comment: I'm totally baffled by what you're asking. Are you genuinely surprised that the total energy of a single object fails to be conserved, when that object is part of a system that's interacting with other objects? Why on Earth would you expect it to be?

Comment: No, I am not surprised at all. I just want a short and formal answer.

Comment: Energy conservation only applies to the entire system, not to part of the system. That short enough?

Comment: Ted, it does not answer the question. The answer should start with: "The ball energy in a moving RF is not conserved because ...".

Comment: And should it also say "Simon says"? Feel free to tack that phrase onto the beginning of my previous comment: "The ball's energy in a moving reference frame is not conserved because energy conservation only applies to the entire system, not to just part of the system."

Comment: And how about the rest RF? No, you do not answer as I like.

Comment: I don't understand the question and frankly doubt your seriousness in asking it. I'm done.

Comment: The short answer I have been looking for from all of you is the following: "Because in a moving RF the ball potential energy depends explicitly on time."